# Solr - sort results based on the distance (lat and long) and search keyword relevance

Tags: solr

I am working on the search functionality where I am trying to sort the results based on the distance and search keyword relevance but it is not working as expected. When I try with the search keyword only without the location then the search keyword relevance works fine using the sort by score. The below is some highlights of my coding:

```
var query = PredicateBuilder.True<CustomSearchResultItem>();
query = query1.Or(x => x.Name.Contains(exactKeyword).Boost(10f));
query = query1.Or(x => x.Title.Contains(exactKeyword).Boost(2f));
query = query1.Or(x => x.Keywords.Contains(exactKeyword).Boost(1f));
 
//set up coordinates
Coordinate coordinates = new Coordinate(lat, lon);
//Select based on radius
query = query.WithinRadius(s => s.Location, coordinates, Filter.Radius);

               
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter.SearchKeyword))
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x["score"]);
}
else if (Filter.HasLocation)
{
    query = query.OrderByDistance(s => s.Location, new Coordinate(Filter.Latitude, Filter.Longitude)).ThenByDescending(x => x["score"]);
}
```

When I looked at the final query generated by Solr I saw that it checks for the distance as well using the 'score' field to sort the results (I can see `score=distance` in the query) and in the sort parameter it shows the 'score' a couple of times - I think that one is for the distance and another one - for the search keyword relevance.

> q=(({!geofilt pt=50.13536985,8.946084 sfield=coordinate_rpt d=29 score=distance} AND *:*) AND ((name_t:(*test*))^10 OR (title_t:(*test*))^2 OR keywords_t:(*test*)^2))&start=0&rows=10&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(custom_index)&wt=xml&sort=score asc,score desc

Did anyone come across this logic? Any suggestions on how to sort the result by distance and keyword?

Comment: So you want to sort by keyword only if distance is equal? Or sort by distance only when keyword score is equal? For `Score` you should be able to use `ThenByDescending`, if you want to first sort by distance and then by score. I'm not sure if there is `ThenByDistance` as well

Comment: I was looking the result based on the location (lat and long with radius considered-it may include other locations as well in the results) and keyword relevance on top if both location and keyword applied in the search